# how to create automatically names for vectors in a loop

Tags: r, loops

I am new in R. I want to create several vectors in a loop. I just want to add a suffix for each vector created such as vector.name1, vector.name2. Then I would like to access these vectors in my process.  How do I this in R?

```
a <- 1

for (a in 1:12)

{

vector.name#a# <- c(100,200,300,400)

}

first.vector <- vector.name1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend putting all the vectors in a list that you can iterate over.

```
a<-list()
for (i in 1:12)
{
    a[[i]]<-c(1,2,3)
}
```

For an intro to lists, see introduction http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list

Comment: ...and then name the list all at once via something like `names(a) <- paste0("vector.name",seq_along(a))`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need.